# "Missing cookie \"access_token_cookie\""

Tags: flask, cookies, flask-jwt-extended

guys. I have been searching all over the internet but I could not get what is the problem with my code. I am actually a Frontend developer. However, I am trying to learn Python Flask for backend part of my project.

Here is the code for login endpoint and another one which can be accessed only after we are logged in.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone_number = request.form.get("phone_number")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        user = Auth.query.filter_by(phone_number=phone_number).first()
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            userlogin = UserLogin().create(user)
            rm = True if request.form.get('remainme') else False
            login_user(user, remember=rm)
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=phone_number)
            response = jsonify(access_token=access_token, role=user.role)
            set_access_cookies(response, access_token)
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
            return response
        else:
            return jsonify(status=False), 401
    return redirect(url_for("all_tours"))
```

```
@app.route("/admin/all_tours")
@jwt_required()
def all_tours():
    all_tours = Tour.query.filter_by(owner=get_jwt_identity()).all()
    response = jsonify(all_tours=[i.serialize for i in all_tours])
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    return response
```

When I try to send request to use **all_tours** endpoint, I get
`msg: "Missing cookie \"access_token_cookie\""`

Have no idea what is wrong.
I even tried to add these lines into `def all_tours():`

```
access_token = request.headers['Authorization'].replace("Bearer ", "")
set_access_cookies(response, access_token)
```

But still useless. Could you please help me to get an idea how to fix it, please?

Comment: Have you ever found any solution?

Comment: Any solution @Sabina ?

Comment: Is your frontend is on a different domain than your backend? If so, the browser won't save the cookie (this called a Cross-domain cookie, and they aren't generally accepted any more). Your frontend appears to be localhost (taken from your Access-Control-Allow-Origin line). Is your backend localhost as well or a different domain/server? If it's localhost then you should be able to access it (you might need to adjust some server cookie settings).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies for more explanation as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain if this is applicable to you.